# Regression Webtoon where the female lead died due to the duke killing her. Time travel happens and she gets adopted by the same duke

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, webcomics

1. The female lead was abandoned by the male protagonists in a fire, because they forgot about her since the OGFL (Original Female Lead) was there
2. She gets a burn scar on her face because of that
3. Later she gets kidnapped and get by the duke (I think he is actually her father)
4. Due to misunderstandings she is treated  as a villain because the MLs (Male Leads) think she is bullying the OGFL
5. Not sure but I think the MC (Main Character) and OGFL are saint candidates, I think getting taught in a church
6. After she gets killed by the duke, she is reincarnated and then gets adopted by the same guy who killed her

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  What site/platform?  Also, can you spell out, or at least define, your initialisms?  Most people will recognize "ML" by now, but I have no idea what "OGFL" means.

Comment: @DavidW - 'OGFL' means original female lead. For context, many of the manhwa users seek to identify here involve a Korean woman waking up as a character inside the world of a historical romance novel she'd read. Often, the character she wakes up as is a side character/villainess, rather than the main character of the novel's plot. As such, those manhwa effectively have two female leads; one being the main character from our perspective, and the other being the main character from the in-universe novel's perspective. The latter may be referred to as the original female lead.

Comment: @Nani - What colour was the main character's hair? Also, what colour was the duke's hair, if you recall?

Comment: Are these chronological? i.e. does 6 take place after 2, meaning she only has the scar for a brief period? Also, was this a Korean Manhwa or Chinese manhua?

Comment: Yes it’s chronological. 
She has the scar for chapter 1, as an introduction to her story. She gets a scar, states that she is considered a villainess by male leads, but the original female lead is always nice to her and cares about her. The misunderstandings keep happening, and the end she gets kidnapped by the duke (I think he has black hair), gets killed by him (if I remembered correctly she was killed because they got a wrong person, so the guy gets rid of her) then she travels back before she gets her scar and get adopted by the dude who killed her

Answer (score 2):

The name of the webtoon is ***The Villain’s Precious Daughter***.

[image: The Villain’s Precious Daughter]

From [forum.novelupdates.com](https://forum.novelupdates.com/threads/the-villains-precious-daughter-%EC%95%85%EB%8B%B9%EC%9D%98-%EC%86%8C%EC%A4%91%ED%95%9C-%EB%94%B0%EB%8B%98.148260/):

> Description:
>
> It’s already unfair that I suffered greatly because I closely resembled the Saintess but why did the villain kill me without any mercy at all?
>
> No, actually, it said in the book that I was really bound to die.
>
> ‘My life is already ruined. Of all things, why do I have to be the one to die a ridiculous death?’
>
> There’s still hope! I haven’t met any of the characters yet so I’ll just run away!
>
> But why did the villain collapse in front of me……?
>
> With a lot of effort, I barely saved the life of the villain who was on the brink of death.
>
> But now he’s saying that he wanted to adopt me as his daughter and raise me to be a Saintess?!
>
> Just like that, I decided to become his daughter for a few days before leaving quietly.
>
> “My daughter is a genius. There’s no child that is more angelic in this world other than my daughter.”
>
> ……I think I have coaxed my dad too well.
>
> Even the guys who originally followed the real Saintess started to pay attention to me.
>
> What went wrong? Aren’t you guys supposed to hate me?!

Comment: Does this match the points about a fire and a burn scar?

Comment: Are you the same user who asked this story-ID question? I ask, because you're not using the same account that was used to post the question. If you are the same user, and have lost access to your previous account, we'd be grateful if you'd merge the two accounts by following the instructions provided [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). Doing so will enable you to mark this answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which is this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.

Comment: It does match the point about fire and burn scar, and I’m the same user, the issue is that I can’t merge the accounts for some reason. Tried several times and it showed error

Comment: @Nani What happens if you visit the [Contact](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/contact) form, select "Account Issue", and then select "[I need to merge user profiles](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/contact?topic=4)"? I believe you only need to provide the links to your two profiles. SE staff should take it from there.